# Is there any access to send and receive radio waves using cellphone antenna?

Tags: android, ios, android-hardware

There is so many Walkie Talkie APPs all around the web, that are using WiFi or Bluetooth to transferring the data (at least all the ones I've ever seen) and none is using inner antenna to transmit data over radio waves as a real Walkie Talkie device.

Is there any security reason for it? or is it restricted to access the antenna as a sender/receiver?

Comment: Did you checked out my answer

Comment: yes, and thank you, I am trying to do some research around it and if I found something useful, I will notify here

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for is **peer-to-peer** connection using mobile networks. It is impossible due to the radio services the mobile networks are licensed under vary by country as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3484917/9882579).

Technically as said [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-for-2-or-more-smartphones-to-communicate-peer-to-peer-no-carrier-cells-using-existing-cellular-technology) You need a cellular network provider to communicate between two devices.

If you still wanna make a P2P communication Use Wi-Fi peer-to-peer (P2P) API 
Follow  https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct